# DefaultView.RowFilter not working with date

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview, rowfilter

I am using this code to filter my rows:

```
 (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = 
      string.Format("DATUM > #{0}# AND DATUM < #{1}#", start, end);
```

**`start`** and **`end`** are defined like this:

```
DateTime dt = dateTime_DO.Value;
DateTime dt1 = dateTime_OD.Value;
DateTime start = new DateTime(dt1.Year, dt1.Month, dt1.Day - 1, 23, 59, 59, 59);
DateTime end = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 23, 59, 59, 59);
```

For some reason, it doesn't work. Here is the screenshot of the DataSource structure:

[image]

Here is string it builds up to filter the rows:

`DATUM > #8/1/2019 11:59:59 PM# AND DATUM < #12/1/2019 11:59:59 PM#`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.ToString()` returns the date string in current culture format, while the filter expression will be parsed using the invariant culture not the current culture.

> *All literal expressions must be expressed in the invariant culture locale. When DataSet parses and converts literal expressions, it
>   always uses the invariant culture, not the current culture.* [[docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2)

You can pass the date in the correct format using:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
    "Column >= #{0}#", dateTimeValue);
```

You can also use [standard date and time format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) like this:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,
    "Column >= #{0:d}#", dateTimeValue);
```